# Conditional sums based on grouped columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

Basically, I would like to create a column `ERROR RATE` that takes the sum of the `YES`'s in `ERROR` and divides it by the `NO`'s in `ERROR`, but to have that `ERROR RATE` filtered per `LOCATION` per `DESCRIPTION`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ERROR' : ['YES','YES','NO','NO','YES'],
           'LOCATION' : ['London', 'New York', 'Edinburgh', 'Paris', 'Berlin'],
           'DESCRIPTION' : ['Good', 'Bad', 'Good', 'Bad', 'Bad']})
```

I've tried writing code along the lines:

```
df.groupby(['DESCRIPTION','LOCATION'])['ERROR'].agg()
```

But I'm unsure if a) This is even the correct approach and b) What kind of function I need to write for the `agg()`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you're looking for `groupby` + `value_counts` + `unstack` + `div`?

```
i = df.groupby(['DESCRIPTION' ,'LOCATION']).ERROR.value_counts().unstack(-1)
j = (i.YES / i.NO).to_frame('ERROR_RATE')

j

                       ERROR_RATE
DESCRIPTION LOCATION             
Bad         Berlin            ...
            New York          ...
            Paris             ...
Good        Edinburgh         ...
            London            ...
```

If there are no counts for either `YES` or `NO` for a particular group, then the resulting columns will have `NaN` for those entries in the final result.

---

If you're using `agg`, you need a 3-way groupby.

```
i = df.groupby(['DESCRIPTION','LOCATION','ERROR']).ERROR.count().unstack()
j = (i.YES / i.NO).to_frame('ERROR_RATE')

j
                       ERROR_RATE
DESCRIPTION LOCATION             
Bad         Berlin            ...
            New York          ...
            Paris             ...
Good        Edinburgh         ...
            London            ...
```

`count` is the same as `agg('count')`.